# Save forms in localstorage

Tags: html, forms, local-storage

So, I'm working on a site and I need to save some data that it's introduced on a form. The idea is to save that data to query later, like an "archive" of forms. There is no php, no server side, I need to make it all locally. Is there anyway to manage that ?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what you said. LocalStorage (or one of its variants). What did you try so far and what doesn't work for you? Take a look to [this jQuery plugin](http://shaneriley.tumblr.com/post/1729353009/saving-form-state-with-jquery-and-localstorage) (it manages different local storages too).

Comment: I would like to know if there is anyway to, somehow "automatically", get all data that is introduced in the form. If not, I only see a way to do it: get those values by the id of each element, but that would take alot of time...

Comment: no, you do not need to do it manually. Simply stringify the form with JSON.stringify and then save it locally (see link, you may use LocalStorage, SessionStorage or as final resource a cookie).

Comment: I'm not very used to work with json, but i'll check it. Whick link where you talking about ? Thanks ;)

Comment: The link in my first comment! :) I dup here: http://shaneriley.tumblr.com/post/1729353009/saving-form-state-with-jquery-and-localstorage

Comment: check [garlic](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Garlic.js) ,might be it turned helpful . if not,check its source code,there you may get some clue .

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

JS

```
//first check to see how many form records exist, if none set to 0 in storage
if (!localStorage.getItem('forms')) {
    localStorage.setItem('forms', 0);
}
else {
    forms = localStorage.getItem('forms');
}

//increment to the next form entry
forms++;

//save the form data to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('form.' + forms + '.firstName', document.getElementById('firstName'));

//lastly, save the number of forms to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('forms', forms);
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" />
```

This will yield a record in `localStorage` labeled *form.1.firstName*.  Output would just be another simple check of the number of form records, and looping through the iterations.